# Clear a UILabel text and reset it again in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilabel

I have a UILabel set its text.But when I check for some condition and try to
change the text of UILabel if  condition not met then Im getting the other other text on already present text of UILabel i.e both texts are overlapping..First I want to clear the present text and reset same UILabel to other text ..How can i do it ?

Im doing this

```
label.text=@"Welcome";
if(check for some condition)
{
  label.text=@"Sorry";
}
```

But both texts are overlapping on each other...Where Im going wrong?

Comment: There must be two labels. Changing the text of a single UILabel would not result in overlapping text.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear label first

```
label.text = @"";
```

and then give some value to the label

```
label.text = @"Sorry";
```

I know it's silly but sometimes it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
label.text = nil;
```

And after the condition, you reassign the text.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with Swift 3. It was some intermittent that at times and a text exchange look like a label. I have decided as follows:

```
 self.label.text = "00:00:00"
 self.label.setNeedsLayout()
```